How to create a custom menu and rename it in Excel?
I have had some success in creating my own added  menu but it appears as "Add-Ins" I want to rename it as "Macro Menu".
I was able to research and find information form alternative resources, below is a mixture of resource code and my own.
Also, is there a way to resize the buttons?
This code I have is in the initial "ThisWorkbook":
'http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=427
    Private Const COMMANDBAR_NAME As String = "Menu"
    Private Const BUTTON_CAPTION As String = "Macros" ' Open
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbarcontrols.add
    'https://bettersolutions.com/vba/enumerations/msocontroltype.htm
    'https://github.com/areed1192/sigma_coding_youtube/blob/master/vba/vba-advanced/commandbar-object/CommandbarControls%20Object.bas
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61918089/adding-macro-to-add-ins-tab-custom-toolbars
'franken start
    Dim objCommandBar As CommandBar
    Dim objButton As CommandBarButton
    ' Try to get the Commandbar (if it exists)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objCommandBar = Me.CommandBars(COMMANDBAR_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    
     If (objCommandBar Is Nothing) Then
        ' Create the commandbar
        On Error Resume Next
        Set objCommandBar = Application.CommandBars.Add(Name:=COMMANDBAR_NAME, Position:=msoBarTop, MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)
        On Error GoTo 0
        'msoBarTypeNormal
           'msoBarTypeMenuBar
        'msoBarTypePopup
            'msoBarTop
        'msoBarPopup
        ' Valid commandbar?
        
        If (Not objCommandBar Is Nothing) Then
            ' Add the buttons to the command bar
            With objCommandBar
       
       
            
                ' Add button
                Set objButton = objCommandBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
                 ' Set the button properties
                With objButton
                    .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
                    .Caption = "Clear"
                    .FaceId = 456
                    .TooltipText = "Clear"
                    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!Clear"
                    .Height = 100
                     .Width = 100
                End With
          
                Set objButton = objCommandBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
                With objButton
                    .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
                    .Caption = "Combine_DF"
                    .FaceId = 1774
                    .TooltipText = "Combine_DF_Reports"
                    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!Combine_DF_Reports"
                    .Height = 100
                     .Width = 100

                End With
               Set objButton = objCommandBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
              With objButton
                    .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
                    .Caption = "Inbound_Reports"
                    .FaceId = 526
                    .TooltipText = "Combine_Inbound_Reports"
                    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!Combine_Inbound_Reports"
                    .Height = 100
                    .Width = 100

                End With
                Set objButton = objCommandBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
                With objButton
                    .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
                    .Caption = "Production"
                    .FaceId = 747
                    .TooltipText = "Tester Move_Production"
                    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!Move_Production"
                    .Height = 100
                     .Width = 100
                
                    
                End With
        With Application
        .ShowToolTips = True
        .LargeButtons = True
        .ColorButtons = True
        '.Caption = "&Menu" 'names the menu item
         End With
                
                ' Show the command bar
                .Position = msoBarTop
                .RowIndex = msoBarRowLast
                .Visible = True
    
                
    MsgBox ("Macro's are located on the Add-In's menu tab")
                
            End With
        End If
    End If
    
    
'franken end
     'Dim cmbBar As CommandBar
   ' Dim cmbControl As CommandBarControl
   ' Set cmbBar = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar")
  '  Set cmbControl = cmbBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, Temporary:=True) 'adds a menu item to the Menu Bar
   ' With cmbControl
    '    .Caption = "&Menu" 'names the menu item
    '    With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton) 'adds a dropdown button to the menu item
    '        .Caption = "Clear" 'adds a description to the menu item
     '       .OnAction = "Clear" 'runs the specified macro
    '       .FaceId = 20 'assigns an icon to the dropdown
     '   End With
     '   With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
     '       .Caption = "Combine_DF"
     '       .OnAction = "Combine_DF_Reports"
     '       .FaceId = 108
     '   End With
      '  With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
     '       .Caption = "Inbound_Reports"
     '       .OnAction = "Combine_Inbound_Reports"
     '       .FaceId = 318
     '   End With
        'https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/face-ids-2003.htm
      '  With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
      '      .Caption = "Production"
      '      .OnAction = "Move_Production"
     '       .FaceId = 219
     '   End With
   ' End With
    'https://www.coragi.com/tips-and-tricks/excel/excel-vba-adding-custom-button-to-the-toolbar-or-ribbon/
    'https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/assigning-macro-to-a-commandbar-by-vba.28674/
    
    
'Set Mypopup = Mycbar.Controls.Add(msoControlPopup)
' create new commandbar control (popup menu type) on custom menu
'With Mypopup
'.BeginGroup = True ' start new group
'.Caption = "TO Menu Items" ' mouseover text
'.Tag = "TOMenu" ' used for identification
'End With
    
End Sub
 
 
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next 'in case the menu item has already been deleted
    Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("My Macros").Delete 'delete the menu item
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Try to remove the iTrade command bar
    Call Application.CommandBars(COMMANDBAR_NAME).Delete
    
    ' Restore error handling
    On Error GoTo 0
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Try to remove the iTrade command bar
    Call Application.CommandBars(Menu).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' Restore error handling
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Try to remove the iTrade command bar
    Call Application.CommandBars(TMenu).Delete
    
    ' Restore error handling
    On Error GoTo 0
    
End Sub

Private Sub Refresh()
Call Workbook_Open
End Sub


still researching - helpful site is
https://jkp-ads.com/rdb/win/section2.htm
